# Docker Entrypoint Script To Support One or Two or Both Commands (namely npm config & npm run)

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm, testcafe

I run tests with testcafe & cucumberjs using docker which is built on top of nodejs. The test run are initiated via npm scripts. I detail the workflow below...

1) Git pull pre built docker image

2) Optionally set a 'config' parameter in the package.json file for example...`npm config set packageJson:task-profile auto-regression-chrome`

3) Execute the runner script i.e. `npm run e2e-test`

my shell script is able to cater for 3 only but I'd to evolve so that it caters for 2) & 3). My shell script at present looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$1" == 'npm' ] && [ "$2" == 'run' ]; then
    shift 2

    XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH=${SCREEN_WIDTH-1280}
    XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT=${SCREEN_HEIGHT-720}

    dbus-daemon --session --fork
    Xvfb :1 -screen 0 "${XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT}x24" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    export DISPLAY=:1.0
    fluxbox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    exec npm run "$@"
fi


# otherwise, just run whatever command was passed on
exec "$@"
```

Any ideas on how to evolve the script so to cater for 2) & 3). Typically I clone the image & execute the runner command but it would be nice to have a shell script that allows me to set some npm config first and execute npm run.

More details re intention:

Looking at https://github.com/bhreinb/SYSTAC#running-tests-on-docker

I do the following when running tests on docker

1) Build the docker image

`docker build --no-cache -t bhreinb/systac .`

2) Run the tests on docker and throw away the image...

`docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/e2e/:/opt/systac/e2e bhreinb/systac npm run e2e-test`

The limitation is the config needs to be setup in source control before running the tests. I want to be able to dynamically update the config, run the tests and throw away the image using the one command i.e.

`docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/e2e/:/opt/SYSTAC/e2e -v $PWD/reports/:/opt/SYSTAC/reports/ bhreinb/SYSTAC npm config set packageJson:task-profile auto-regression-chrome && npm run e2e-test`

hope that makes sense?

Comment: What exactly do you find challenging here? Are you trying to figure out a syntax for enabling "2" conveniently or do you genuinely have trouble implement code to perform the actual task?

Comment: You could easily if somewhat clumsily have your script accept an optional configuration parameter, like `myscript -v packageJson:task-profile=auto-regression-chrome npm run e2e-test`

Comment: And still please [edit] this information into the question itself. Comments should not be used to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tentative quick hack to allow you to pass in configuration parameters with `-v` options.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Quick and dirty option processing
while [ $1 = '-v' ]; do
    case $2 in
      *=*)
        option=${2%=*}
        npm config set "$option" "${2#$option}"
        shift 2;;
      *)
        echo "$0: Fatal error: argument to -v must contain =" >&2
        exit 127;;
    esac
done

# Aside; use = not == inside [ ... ]    
if [ "$1" = 'npm' ] && [ "$2" = 'run' ]; then
    shift 2

    XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH=${SCREEN_WIDTH-1280}
    XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT=${SCREEN_HEIGHT-720}

    dbus-daemon --session --fork
    Xvfb :1 -screen 0 "${XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT}x24" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    export DISPLAY=:1.0
    fluxbox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    exec npm run "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Usage:

```
docker run --rm -it \
   -v $PWD/e2e/:/opt/SYSTAC/e2e \
   -v $PWD/reports/:/opt/SYSTAC/reports/ \
  bhreinb/SYSTAC \
   scriptname -v foo=bar \
      -v packageJson:task-profile=auto-regression-chrome \
      -v baz=quux \
     npm run gargleblaster --demo --crash --splinters
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion....I'll try this...

within the docker file https://github.com/bhreinb/SYSTAC/blob/master/Dockerfile that builds the image

I set the entrypoint to `docker-entrypoint.sh` so I assume the scriptname you refer to in usage would be `docker-entrypoint.sh`. I guess in usage I can drop the scriptname as before I didn't need to explicitly state that before.

Comment: It will need to be specified because otherwise `docker` will intepret the `-v` options by itself.  Maybe you want to specify some other interface (perhaps with `--` to signal the end of Docker options?) but specifying the script name explicitly seems like by far the simplest solution.